# help me resolve the below code

Tags: apex, visualforce

## Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" Controller="AccountTest">
<apex:form style="text-align:center;color:purple;">
<h1>
USER PROFILE</h1>
 <!--<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" style="width: 500px;">-->
        <div style="width: 500px;margin-left: 65%;"> 
        <apex:commandButton value="edit" action="{!Editthesection}" immediate="true" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:LightBlue;width:150px;"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!Savethesection}" id="saveButton" immediate="true" onclick="save" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:LightBlue;width:150px;"/>

        </div>
        <!--</apex:pageBlockButtons>-->
<apex:pageBlock title="{!AccountTest.Name} INFORMATION" >
 <div class="pbSubsection">
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!!AccountTest}">
         <body style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.19);width: 1366px;"></body>


        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.industry}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.ownership}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.type}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.Phone}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.Website}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!AccountTest.AnnualRevenue}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!AccountTest.Fax}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection></div>

        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!AccountTest}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.industry}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.ownership}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.type}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.Phone}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.Website}"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!AccountTest.Fax}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!Savethesection}">

        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.industry}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.ownership}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.type}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.Phone}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.Website}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!AccountTest.AnnualRevenue}"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!AccountTest.Fax}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>




</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## CONTROLLER

```
public class AccountTest{
 public Account AccountTest { get; set; } 
 public boolean editSection {get;set;}
 public boolean saveSection {get;set;}
  public AccountTest () 
  {
   AccountTest = new Account(); 

   }


        public AccountTest.AccountTest(ApexPages.StandardController sc) 
        {
         sc.edit();
         sc.save();
        }
    public PageReference Editthesection() { 
                   //editSection =true;
                   insert AccountTest;
                   return null;  
                             }

         public PageReference Savethesection() {  
                    // saveSection =true;  
                     PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
                     pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                     update AccountTest;
                     return null;  
                             }
    }
```

Comment: Hi jessy, and welcome to SFSE! We can't really help you with just a bunch of code, we need to know what that problem or error you're having. See [ask] for more details on what makes a good question. We look forward to helping you!

Comment: on executing this vf code,this error is showing.(Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Object).kindly help me resolve this as i am new to salesforce.@sfdcfox

Answer (score 1):

In your vf page `rendered` attribute is expecting a boolean value, but you are passing an object value like `rendered="{!!AccountTest}"`.

Modify your code by 
`rendered="{!AccountTest != null}"`.

Comment: thanks reshma! but still error is showing(Error: Cannot convert the value of '{!AccountTest}' to the expected type.)

Comment: update your current code in question

Comment: the task assigned to me is to display the account details with edit and save buttons. I am working now for the code.I am a beginner now,can u guide me reshma

Comment: We can't provide complete code instead will help you to sort out issues with your code.